# Can't connect to Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

There are exaclty similar questions but nothing works for me.

I have a postgres installed on a server running Ubuntu Server 16.04.

In the postgresql.conf I have set:

```
listen_addresses = '*'                                          
port = 5432
```

The status of postgres gives:

> ● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS    Loaded: loaded
>   (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset:
>   enabled)    Active: active (exited) since Wed 2019-06-19 09:30:25 UTC;
>   3min 24s ago   Process: 23683 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited,
>   status=0/SUCCESS)  Main PID: 23683 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>
> Jun 19 09:30:25 ip-172-31-43-128 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL
>   RDBMS... Jun 19 09:30:25 ip-172-31-43-128 systemd[1]: Started
>   PostgreSQL RDBMS.

I have setup postgresql in streaming replication mode with 3 slaves.

My pg_hba.conf file looks like this:

```
 # Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all             all             172.31.43.128/24        md5
host    replication     all             172.31.32.119/32        trust   # the slave1
host    replication     all             172.31.40.107/32        trust   # the slave2
host    replication     all             172.31.44.8/32          trust   # the slave3

host    postgres        pgpool          172.31.33.203/32        trust   # the client
host    postgres        postgres        172.31.33.203/32        trust   # new
host    all             all             172.31.33.203/32        md5     # the client
```

I try to connect to master instance in python:

```
import psycopg2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
import time
import pprint

def connect_postgrs():
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=my_pgpool_db user=postgres password=antonis host=172.31.43.128")  
        print "Connected"
    except psycopg2.Error as e:
        print str(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    connect_postgrs()
```

and I get the error:

> could not connect to server: Connection timed out     Is the server
>   running on host "172.31.43.128" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on
>   port 5432?

command: `netstat -nlt` gives the following output:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 172.31.43.128:5432      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Does anyone knows what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you restarted Postgres after setting `listen_addresses = '*'`?

Usually, you would see

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Instead of

`tcp        0      0 172.31.43.128:5432      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN`

Comment: @Antonis are you trying to connect from a different host? if so can you ping `172.31.43.128` from the host you're trying? What about `telnet 172.31.43.128 5432`?

Comment: I am trying to connect from my local machine. telnet seems not to work. It stucks on Trying 172.31.43.128...

Comment: That's your problem.. you need to be able to reach your Postgres server. Where is this Postgres server hosted? is in a VM? is it physically on the same network you are?

Comment: no. it is on a vm. I have setup the key and my config file. So I can access the machine using ssh masternode. This command works

Comment: Well.. Check the firewall in the VM (if CentOS / RHEL check selinux in `/etc/selinux/config`). It looks like you do not have connectivity between your laptop and your Postgres VM. Therefore, you won't be able to connect to Postgres. You need to solve this problem first. Edit your question and post more information about your setup so we help more.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change this entry in your pg_hba.conf

```
    host    all             all             172.31.43.128/24        md5
```

to either one of:

```
    host    all             all             172.31.43.0/24        md5
    host    all             all             172.31.43.128/32        md5
```

then reload your configuration:

```
  sudo service postgresql reload
```